# Dynamic PHP Pagination Mysqli

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have tried dynamic pagination in php, I have implemented the code and that works fine too, but the real problem here is I get all page numbers in the URL I have already visited, maybe because I am using `&pn` in query string instead of `?pn`, and I need to use `&pn` in my condition instead of `?pn` so that I can fetch values of particular vendor type via `$_GET`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php

    require "conn.php";

?>

<?php
        $qryfav = "SELECT favicon FROM website_details WHERE website_id = 0";
        $qfav = mysqli_query($conn, $qryfav);
        $rowfav = mysqli_fetch_array($qfav);
?>
    
<head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <title>BookYourEvents - Vendor List</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon_thumbnail/<?php echo $rowfav['favicon']; ?>" height = "16px" width = "16px">

        <!-- fraimwork - css include -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- icon css include -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/fontawesome-all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/flaticon.css">

        <!-- carousel css include -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/slick-theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">

        <!-- others css include -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/calendar.css">

        <!-- color switcher css include -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/colors/style-switcher.css">
        <link id="color_theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/colors/default.css">

        <!-- custom css include -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
        
</head>

<body class="default-header-p">
        

        <!-- backtotop - start -->
        <div id="thetop" class="thetop"></div>
        <div class='backtotop'>
            <a href="#thetop" class='scroll'>
                <i class="fas fa-angle-double-up"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- backtotop - end -->


        <!-- preloader - start -->
        <div id="preloader"></div>
        <!-- preloader - end -->


        <!-- header-section - start
        ================================================== -->

        <?php 

            include "header-1.php";
        
        ?>
        
        <!-- header-section - end
        ================================================== -->


        <!-- altranative-header - start
        ================================================== -->
        
        <!-- altranative-header - end
        ================================================== -->


        <!-- breadcrumb-section - start
        ================================================== -->
        
        <!-- breadcrumb-section - end
        ================================================== -->


        <!-- event-search-section - start
        ================================================== -->
        <?php

            $vendor_query_string = $_GET['vendor_type'];

            echo $vendor_query_string."<br>";

            $protocol = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) ? "https://" : "http://";
 
            $url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            echo $url."<br>"; // Outputs: Full URL

        ?>
        <section id="event-search-section" class="event-search-section clearfix" style="background-image: url(assets/images/special-offer-bg.png);">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- section-title - start -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <small class="sub-title">Find best event on BYE!</small>
                            <h2 class="big-title">Search<strong>Vendors</strong></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- section-title - end -->

                    <!-- search-form - start -->

                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="search-form form-wrapper">
                            <form action="user-side-list-view-search-vendors.php?vendor_type=<?php echo $vendor_query_string ; ?>" method="POST">

                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="title">Vendor Name</span>
                                        <div class="form-item">
                                            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter Vendor Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit_search" class="submit-btn">Search Vendor now</button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </form>                                 
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- search-form - end -->
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- event-search-section - end
        ================================================== -->


        <?php

        //The First Query to get total count of rows
        $qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vendor_detail INNER JOIN vendor_master ON vendor_detail.vendor_id = vendor_master.vendor_id WHERE vendor_type = '$vendor_query_string' AND vendor_is_active = 1";

        $q = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($q);

        //Here we have the total row count
        $rows = $row[0];

        //This is the number of results we want to get display per page
        $page_rows = 5;

        //This tells us page number of our last page
        $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

        //This make sure last cannot be last then one
        if ($last < 1)
        {
            $last = 1;
        }

        //Establish the $pagenum variable
        $pagenum = 1;

        //Get Pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is equal to 1.
        if (isset($_GET['pn']))
        {
            $pagenum  = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','',$_GET['pn']);
        }

        //This makes sure that page number isnt below 1, or more than our last page
        if($pagenum < 1)
        {
            $pagenum = 1;
        }
        elseif ($pagenum > $last)
        {
            $pagenum = $last;
        }

        //This sets the range of rows to query for the chosen $pagenum
        $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows.',' .$page_rows;
        

        //qry again but just for one page with limit
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM vendor_detail INNER JOIN vendor_master ON vendor_detail.vendor_id = vendor_master.vendor_id WHERE vendor_type = '$vendor_query_string' AND vendor_is_active = '1' ORDER BY vendor_detail_id DESC $limit ";

        

        $q = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

        //This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
        
        $textline = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";

        //Establish the pagination control Variables
        $paginationctrls = '';

        //If There is more than 1 page worth of results
        if ($last!=1)
        {
            
        /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.*/
        if ($pagenum > 1)
        {
            $previous = $pagenum - 1;
            $paginationctrls.='<li class="page-item prev-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$url.'&pn='.$previous.'">Prev</a></li>';

            //Render Clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
            for ($i=$pagenum - 4; $i < $pagenum; $i++)
            { 
                if ($i > 0)
                {
                    $paginationctrls.='<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$url.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li> ';
                }
            }
        }

        //Render the target pagenumber, but without it being a link
        $paginationctrls.='<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">'.$pagenum.'</a> </li>';

        //Render the clickable number links that should appear on the right
        for ($i=$pagenum+1; $i <= $last ; $i++)
        { 
            $paginationctrls.='<li class="page-item "><a class="page-link" href="'.$url.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> </li> ';
            if ($i>=$pagenum+4)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
        if ($pagenum != $last)
        {
            $next = $pagenum + 1;
            $paginationctrls.=' <li class="page-item next-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$url.'&pn='.$next.'">Next</a> </li>';
        }


        }

        $list = '';
        
        ?>


        <!-- event-section - start
        ================================================== -->
        <section id="event-section" class="event-section bg-gray-light sec-ptb-100 clearfix">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- sidebar-section - start -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="sidebar-section">

                            <!-- Add to Calendar - start -->
                            <div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
                                Add to Calendar
                                <span class="start">06/18/2015 09:00 AM</span>
                                <span class="end">06/18/2015 11:00 AM</span>
                                <span class="timezone">Europe/Paris</span>
                                <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
                                <span class="description">Description of the event</span>
                                <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
                                <span class="organizer">Organizer</span>
                                <span class="organizer_email">Organizer e-mail</span>
                                <span class="all_day_event">false</span>
                                <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Add to Calendar - end -->

                            <!-- map-wrapper - start -->
                            
                            <!-- map-wrapper - end -->

                            <!-- spacial-event-wrapper - start -->
                            
                            <!-- spacial-event-wrapper - end -->
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- sidebar-section - end -->

                    <!-- - start -->
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

                        <div class="search-result-form">

                            <ul class="nav event-layout-btngroup">
                                <li><a class="active" href=""><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></a></li>
                                <li><a href="user-side-grid-view-vendors.php?vendor_type=<?php echo $vendor_query_string?>"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-content">

                            <div id="list-style" class="tab-pane fade in active show">

                                <?php
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q))
                                { ?>

                                <!-- event-item - start -->
                                <div class="event-list-item clearfix">


                                    <!-- event-image - start -->
                                    <div class="event-image">
                                        
                                        <img src="../vendor/vendor_thumbnail/<?php echo $row['vendor_pic']; ?>" alt="Image_not_found">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- event-image - end -->

                                    <!-- event-content - start -->
                                    <div class="event-content">
                                        <div class="event-title mb-15">
                                            <h3 class="title">
                                                <strong> <?php echo $row['vendor_name']; ?></strong>
                                            </h3>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="discription-text mb-30">
                                            <?php echo $row['vendor_description']; ?>
                                        </p>
                                        <div class="event-info-list ul-li clearfix">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <span class="icon">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <div class="info-content">
                                                        <small>Owner Name</small>
                                                        <h3> <?php echo $row['vendor_fname']." ".$row['vendor_lname'];?></h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <span class="icon">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                    <div class="info-content">
                                                        <small>Package Price</small>
                                                        <h3><?php echo $row['vendor_per_package_price']; ?></h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="vendor-overview-details.php?vendor_detail_id=<?php echo $row['vendor_detail_id']?>" class="tickets-details-btn">
                                                        See More Details
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- event-content - end -->

                                </div>
                                <!-- event-item - end -->
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>


                                </div>
                                <!-- event-item - end -->


                                    

                                    <div>
                                        
                                        <p><?php echo $textline ;?></p>
                                        <p><?php echo $list ;?></p>
                                        <div id="pagination controls"></div>
                                    </div>


                                 <div class="pagination ul-li clearfix">
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php echo $paginationctrls ;?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                            
                    </div>

                </div>
                    <!-- - end -->
                    
            </div>
            
        </section>
        <!-- event-section - end
        ================================================== -->





        <!-- default-footer-section - start
        ================================================== -->
        
            <?php
            
                include "footer.php";

            ?>

        <!-- default-footer-section - end
        ================================================== -->


        <!-- fraimwork - jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- carousel jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

        <!-- map jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC61_QVqt9LAhwFdlQmsNwi5aUJy9B2SyA"></script>

        <!-- calendar jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/atc.min.js"></script>

        <!-- others jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jarallax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>

        <!-- gallery img loaded - jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

        <!-- multi countdown - jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>

        <!-- color panel - jquery include -->
        <!-- <script src="assets/js/style-switcher.js"></script> -->

        <!-- custom jquery include -->
        <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

method, so can someone help with this query?

Comment: `?pn` and `&pn` are identical to eachother to PHP

Comment: Replace "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" with "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"

Comment: @mail2bapi If i replace "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" with "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']", then there will be an error of Object Not Found as the page will not be able to fetch vendor_type via $_GET ?vendor_type=Photostudios, so i have already tried that method

Comment: @KhemilJariwala You will also need to use QUERY_STRING along with PHP_SELF